# Beginner question- font limitations

Tags: website-design

I am a graphic designer veering off into the world of UX design. Currently, I´m just beginner learning through courses, so please excuse my lack of knowledge in the field.

My question pertains to the limitation of using only 2 fonts in web design. I wanted to know if it is possible to create a call to action with other font pairings which are not a part of the 2 font limitation by turning them into SVGs.
Ex: a call to action using the fonts: Sign Painter (house script)and Rockwell (regular) turned into SVG.

Is this frowned upon? I have seen some clothing websites which make use of other fonts in images or maybe I am being tricked by variations of the same font.
Thanks in advance for your responses!

Comment: Hey Andrea, which limitation of using only 2 fonts in web design do you mean? You can use as many fonts as you like. There is merely a suggestion to not use too many fonts as the website could get very busy and hard to understand.

Comment: Hi Nash!  Thanks for your response. I see. Regarding the limitations, I just keep hearing that coming up in courses and from other designers. I guess it really just depends how fast I want the site to be and how neat it looks. 
 Does the same apply to color choices I also hear that we should only use 2 or 3 colors?

Comment: It is a guideline for new designers to focus on getting the interaction design and user flow right and not focus too much on visuals. Also, in real world projects development resources are scarce, so people might not be too happy if your design features 99+ fonts and 99+ colors. If a color or typeface is important for the brand or the understanding of the user, I don't see any point in artificially limiting yourself to 2 colors or typefaces.

Comment: Thanks Nash! I will take all you mentioned into account!

Comment: Hi Andrea, welcome to UXSE and thanks for your question. Regardless of your experience level in this field, remember that UX design is a multi-disciplinary field and that asking and answering questions is the best way to learn :) I would also take what you learn from courses with a grain of salt since you also know that what's taught in the courses isn't always how things work in the real world. There are rules in UX but also good reasons for deviating from them time to time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**A limitation is not a restriction.**

The limitations are set by the designer and can be as free as he/she decides, for example how many colors there will be on a website or how many fonts.

The restrictions are outside the decision of a professional, for example, avoid using colors similar to the background color in interactive elements, or avoid texts smaller than 5 px in the relevant information.

In the case of the fonts to be used in a web page, they can be all possible or necessary, it only depends on the design guidelines.

If the question is: "having a couple of official fonts, is it possible to use another one as an image in some elements"? The answer is yes, it's possible.

If the question is: "what stylistic conditioning must be foreseen in case of using third fonts in graphic elements within the same website? The answer is a bit more complicated and here we should already talk about certain design considerations. Among others and referring to the text of similar or equal type of information in a project:

- Avoid fonts of the same style with a different build structure: Helvetica Regular and Arial Narrow
- Avoid fonts of the same style with different stroke modulation: Helvetica Regular and Optima
- Avoid using fonts of the same style with different character structures: Helvetica Regular and Futura
- Avoid using fonts of the same style but with different typographic variables depending on the case: one font for regular text and another for italics. If possible use the same font in all visual variables.

As you can see, none of these guidelines are restrictions, but rather an open door to finding solutions without the need to make typographical leaps, for example, using a font with the greatest number of variations, always depending on the magnitude of the project.

One last thought:

A good graphic designer is always able to see graphic options in every limitation.

Comment: All good advice, but in other words, all the same stuff that OP knows from their existing graphic design career. The question suggests that they think the limitation here is a technical one related to serving font files to the client.

Comment: It was a great answer and for someone who is a beginner in UX/UI it really helped. Thank you so much! I shall take notes!

Answer (score 0):

In UX design fonts play an important role as part of an overall design system that provides consistency and cohesion to the entire user interface. Therefore the introduction of additional fonts increases the overall complexity of the design system/style guide and also the complexity of the user interface (not just to design but also to maintain).

Font pairings is an important aspect of creating a fluent reading experience for the user, and there are many rules around complementary pairing of fonts that provide good balance between legibility and aesthetics. I imagine that's where the idea about 2 fonts might have surfaced as well.

In my experience, most style guides and design systems in the digital realm will have at least three fonts because there has to be at least a backup or default font if it is not supported by the browser or installed in the system (i.e. the 'web safe' or 'OS safe' fonts).

So I hope that answers your question about the limitation of using 2 fonts. But I also want to address the point about turning a font into a SVG for a call-to-action.

The first thing that pops into my head is the accessibility of this call-to-action as it is harder for screen readers and accessibility tools to process images compared to text (you can of course provide metadata and tags for images). The second thing is that it is much harder for developers to maintain and update this component that is not behaving as it normally would, not to mention having to update the design of this component in a roundabout way as well. This has an impact on the overall consistency of the design system for designers and developers.

Finally, as you are working your way through the course, it is important to be able to draw on the fundamental design principles and be prepared to challenge any myths or assumptions that you come across :)

Answer (score 0):

One more important thing to add is that this 2 font limitations probably comes from **loading times** of the websites. If you wish to use custom fonts each font weight is loaded separately. Limiting the number of different weights will help with the page loading times. You can ignore loading times when using **system fonts** (but they are very limited and depended on the platform). There is also a cool trick if you wish to use many font weights called **variable fonts**! They are capable of using smaller kB footprint without sacrificing freedom of different weight or even adding italics to the mix.

https://fonts.google.com/variablefonts

The stylistic chocies were already mentioned, you should just keep in mind that each font combination you create must be then implemented so if possible I would combine very similar styles into one, it is also easier to manage for design system.